# JSF 1.2 Mojarra View State encryption - GZip Error - java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format

Tags: xml, jsf, jsf-1.2

We have our Web application developed in JSF 1.2 (Sun's RI) is deployed in Weblogic 11g with JRockit 1.6 64 bit. We have our View State saving mode as Client. The application is accessed via HTTPS.

As part of a recommendation from 3rd Party Penetration testing, we were recommended to encrypt the View State, which is implemented using the JNDI ENV settings in web.xml.

```
    <env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>com.sun.faces.ClientStateSavingPassword</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>2rEb7Tuf</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>
```

When the application is deployed into our production box (clustered with session affinity), sometime while processing the client request (Certainly not when the application page is loaded into the client browser where the default view state would be sent as part of the Hidden Field), we get GZIP Error "*java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format*". This happens only when the Encryption is enabled.

```
    Servlet failed with IOException
    java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:143)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:58)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:67)
    at  com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.getTreeStructureToRestore(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:166)
    at javax.faces.render.ResponseStateManager.getState(ResponseStateManager.java:215)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Any valuable insight would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By default `com.sun.faces.compressViewState` is `true` when we are setting the view state at client side, so JSF framework will try to compress it using GZIP format. If you set `com.sun.faces.compressViewState` init parameter in `web.xml` to `false`, then the compression won't happen and you can avoid this exception. Give a try.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse BalusC. But we would want to enable GZIP/compression and also we would want to save the sate on the client side. Is there a way we can achieve this circumventing this issue. Thanks in advance.